# Client Credential flow sending 401 error whereas Individual flow is working on Microsoft Graph API

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

Through an Oauth2 client credentials flow, i get an access token which seems to have the right audience, roles... for the Microsoft Graph API.

Nevertheless, a call to the Graph API to get messages a of a specific user sends back :

`{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1c24f471-ebca-489a-8264-8ef4cd66c72d",
            "date": "2019-04-19T10:55:34"
        }
    }
}`

The payload of the token does seem ok :

`{
    "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/customer-tenant-XXXXXXXXXX/",
    "iat": 1555670233,
    "nbf": 1555670233,
    "exp": 1555674133,
    "aio": "42ZgYFgUNyvl6hTle8+nbZH4qu2/DwA=",
    "app_displayname": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "appid": "OUR-ID-XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "appidacr": "2",
    "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/customer-tenant-XXXXXXXXXX/",
    "oid": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
    "roles": [
       "Mail.ReadWrite",
       "Calendars.Read",
       "Directory.Read.All",
       "Chat.Read.All",
       "ChannelMessage.Read.All",
       "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite",
       "Reports.Read.All"
    ],
    "sub": "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
    "tid": "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    "uti": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ",
    "ver": "1.0",
    "xms_tcdt": 1546954974
}`

The exact same authentication flow process on my test company account works perfectly. The only difference is that our customer has a 2016 Hybrid Exchange set-up. The individual flow (Oauth2 authorization code for one user) DO work to access one user mailbox.

Is there any parameter that should be set on customer Exchange configuration to have OAuth2 client_credentials flow working ?

Comment: Can you please share the actual Microsoft Graph API URL that you're hitting? One case I can think of where individual user will work but client credentials will fail (even with correct permissions) is if you're using something like `/me`

Comment: As mentioned it works for another company account with Exchange Online. Indeed I am using this kind of url :`/company_tenant_id/users/user_id/messages`. So I am looking for what could block a client credential flow on an on premises hybrid configuration.

Comment: Seems like that a MS Graph API with Exchange side issue. Please open a new support request in Office365 portal to reach MS Support for this issue.